# How can i differentiate scope variable and ng-model variable from the code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Is there any way to differentiate a scope variable declared from controller or using ng-model directive?
How can I differentiate them in code?

**Example**

`$scope.testScopeVar` & `ng-model="testVal"

I'm really curious to know, Is there any way to do it so?

Comment: what is the reason why you need to differentiate them?

Comment: just want to understand angular scope concept more clearly..

Comment: @SamIam why we can't differentiate them? is there any way to do it.?

Comment: differentiate what? can't even understand what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl i clearly mention what i want. How can i define scope variable is defined using ng-model or directly using scope.variableName.

Comment: @pankajparkar how would you ever use it anyway? Consider binding to objects from third party API's using hashmaps of unknown keys in directives that dynamically create elements and `ng-model`'s that all get saved using `$resource`

Comment: That's good..  @charlietfl can we go for ngModel directive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is **no, you cannot distinguish the origin of scope variables programmatically**. Once they are on the scope, they are Plain Old JavaScript Objects. The best you can do would be to establish a naming convention and adhere to it in your own application code.

Comment: But still thinking that angular should provide mentioned thing